# Filter Twitter Stream by Location in Python

Tags: python, twitter

I'm using the Python wrapper to the Twitter API (not tweepy, but maybe that is my problem). Also, I'm using the Spyder IDE. I can easily filter by track, by I am having trouble determining the exact syntax to filter by location. When I try:

```
auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN,OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                           CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)                         
twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)
twitter_stream = twitter.TwitterStream(auth=twitter_api.auth)
stream = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(locations=[-6.38,49.87,1.77,55.81])
```

I get the error:

```
details: Location track items must be given as pairs of comma separated lat/longs:
[Ljava.lang.String;@1f1dbc92
```

I have tried several variations and nothing seems to work, such passing strings vs. floats. Can someone please explain how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, after a bit of guesswork, apparently the locations parameter ought to be a **string** that contains comma-separated longitude/latitude pairs, with the first pair being the south-west corner and the second pair the north-east corner of the bounding box of interest. So in your example, you should write :

stream = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(locations="-6.38,49.87,1.77,55.81")

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this line `stream = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(locations=[-6.38,49.87,1.77,55.81])`

`locations` should be a list of tuples (lat,lon)

a possible format could be >> `stream = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(locations=[(-6.38,49.87), (1.77,55.81)])`

Comment: I just tried that and it doesn't work. I still get the same error as before. However, I tried using the tweepy module and it works well:
`sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(api))
sapi.filter(locations=[-112.229462,33.301838,-111.943817,33.910315])`